# How to solve `SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution` error in SignalR using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to do real time web page updates using **SignalR**, this is the first time I have tried. My ajax command is calling my server code. But it doesn't return anything from the server side.

Here is the script

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        //Proxy created on the fly
        var job = $.connection.myHub;

        //Declare a function on the hub so the server can invoke it
        job.client.displaystatus = function () {
            getData();
        };

        //Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();

    });

    function getData() {
        //alert('ok');
        var $tb1 = $('#tb1');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetData',
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Success:' + data);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Default.cs code**

```
[WebMethod]
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetData()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        //Make sure the command object does not already have

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Id],[Name],[PricDecimal],[QuantDecimal]FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Product]"))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();


            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                    .Select(x => new Product()
                    {
                        id = x.GetInt32(0),
                        Name = x.GetString(1),
                        PricDecimal = x.GetDecimal(2),
                        QuantDecimal = x.GetDecimal(3)
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }

}


private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender,SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    MyHub.show();
}
```

**Product class in Default.cs file**

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal PricDecimal { get; set; }
    public decimal QuantDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

**MyHub.cs file**

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{    

    public static void show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs file**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.MapSignalR();
    //string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
    //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(cs);
    }
}
```

**Error msg**

> ExceptionType
>   :
>   "System.InvalidOperationException"
>
> Message
>   :
>   "When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance."

Comment: Nobody know about SignalR?

Comment: I cannot believe this,this is stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

I think it's too late, but you need to write this line before new SqlDependency:

```
SqlDependency.Start("connection string");
```